# Laravel Homestead Routing : InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php : View [****] not found

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

After getting my Laravel Homestead up and running, I'm facing a new problem.

Even after some googling, I can't find a solution for setting up routes in Laravel Homestead.

Here is my routes.php (I created files like in the comments) :

```
<?php

// ===============================================
// STATIC PAGES ==================================
// ===============================================

// show a static view for the home page (app/views/home.blade.php)
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});

// about page (app/views/about.blade.php)
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('about');
});

// work page (app/views/work.blade.php)
Route::get('work', array('as' => 'work', function()
{
    return View::make('work');
}));
Route::get('users', function()
{
return View::make('users');
});
```

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: Which page got error home or about or work or users?

Comment: Home page is working fine, but the 3 others give the same "Not Found" error.

Comment: Problems seems to come from View::make.
When I change to View::share('data', [1, 2, 3]);, the page is showing up.

Comment: Are you using Linux? Verify whether those view files you can't access have proper permissions by comparing them with home.blade.php

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX. I checked the files, they're all in 644.

Comment: What is the behavior if you swap view names (for example 'home' => 'work')?

Comment: Try the following: a) copy about.blade.php and rename it to about.php b) change Route::get to Route::any c) ensure that all of your views and parent directories leading to them have proper permissions and owner set. d) Make sure your .blade.php view files are located directly inside views catalog and not in any of subcatalogs. Check if either of those things fixes your problem. Also you should remove your reply with image and post it as link to image in comment because it doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: I was just trying to answer quickly, so I wanted to post images of the results. But I didn't saw anyway to make it within comments. I was tired of Laravel so I decided to drop it to start my app from scratch. Maybe I'll try your solution if I decide to go back to Laravel. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: are you using laravel 4 oder 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel5 the views are located in

**resources/views**

and not in app/views

Place all your views to **resources/views** and it should work.
You get the welcome page because it is shipped by default in Laravel.